# Responsive Twitter bootstrap : <body> and navbar right padding/margin appears when width is < 767/768px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-sass

When I resize the windows below 767/768 px width, the body and navbar get a strange right margin/padding (20px each ; which does a total of 40 white pixels at the right side of the navbar). I can't find if it is a BS normal behavior or if I did something wrong.

The only fragment of css size/padding/margin bootstrap overwriting is :

```
.navbar { margin-bottom: 20px; }
```

Here the HTML :

```
<body>
  <header class='navbar navbar-static-top'>
    <nav class='navbar-inner'>
      <div class='container'>
        <a class='btn btn-navbar' data-target='.nav-collapse' data-toggle='collapse'>
          <div class='icon-bar'></div>
          <div class='icon-bar'></div>
          <div class='icon-bar'></div>
        </a>
        <a href="/" class="brand">Brand Name</a>
        <div class='nav-collapse collapse'>
          <ul class='nav'>
            <li><a href="...">...</a></li>
            <li><a href="...">...</a></li>
            <li><a href="...">...</a></li>
          </ul>
          <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/search" class="navbar-search pull-right" method="get">
            <input class="search-query" id="q" name="q" placeholder="Search" type="text" />
            <input class="hidden" type="submit" value="Find" />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='span12'>
        <!-- ... -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I use bootstrap-sass gem with rails. I'm unsure about `.container` role.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16410659/bootstrap-removing-padding-or-margin-when-screen-size-is-smaller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find anything, so I wrote this hack:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) { body { padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0; } } 
.navbar { margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for a solution.  That said, I'm puzzled. There has to be a better way.  Pull-right should not impact the padding, should it?

Comment: OK, there is a better solution, at least to the issue I was trying to fix, which is navbar-right.  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118310/bootstrap-navbar-align-want-align-to-the-right

Comment: I think I was wrong navbar-right doesn't fix the problem that I had.

Answer (score 0):

Check the padding on the body for that media query. Also for a hack try adding the following code to the media query handling that size:

```
 .navbar-inner{
    left: 0x;
 }
```