# Bootstrap navbar align want align to the right

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm trying to align the navbar to the right. When I use the .pull-right class it's pushing the navbar too much to the right: "off the grid".

What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span3 top_logo"><img src="images/logo_svart.png" width="177" height="60" alt="BETA Team Performance" /></div>
    <div class="span9">
        <div class="navbar navbar-static-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"><strong>MENY <i class="icon-chevron-down icon-white"></i></strong>
                    </button>
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav pull-right">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Start</a></li>
                            ...
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem arises because in bootstrap-responsive.css the `margin-right` is set to 0.

Jsfiddle with a basic mockup [See in browser](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/Q4phr/2/show/)

So you have to provide it with some number to look appropriate, like below:

```
.navbar .nav.pull-right {
     float: right;
    margin-right: 98px; /*set margin this way in your custom styesheet*/
  }
```

The html code to create your desired effect can be written in the following way :

```
<div class="conatiner">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2 top_logo">
        <img width="177" height="60" alt="BETA Team Performance" src="http://placehold.it/177x60">
    </div>
    <div class="span10">
        <div class="navbar navbar-static-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
                    <button data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-navbar"
                    type="button"><strong>MENY <i class="icon-chevron-down icon-white"></i></strong>

                    </button>
                    <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse ">
                        <!-- .nav, .navbar-search, .navbar-form, etc -->
                        <ul class="nav pull-right">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 53):

For anyone arriving here who's using **Bootstrap v3**, just use the included `.navbar-right` on the list element:

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <!-- … -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

try putting your `pull-right` class on the `div.collapse`. That may do the trick.

Comment: It dident solve the problem, the navbar moved like 20pixels to the left but more than half of the navbar is still outside the "grid". Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

In Boostrap 4 you can use `ml-auto` to align the menu to the right:

```
<div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you *do* want to pull something all the way to the right outside the grid (like select language or social buttons) you can create a simple class and add to the `<ul class="nav navbar-nav language">` and style it like so `.language {right:50px;position:absolute;}`. Works really well with using the `.navbar-brand` as a logo to your far left (from an Art Directors eye, anyways).

Answer (score 0):

This here worked for me. Putting `pull-right` in the `div.collapse` doesn't work - it has to be in the un-ordered list class.

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">

 <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
```