# Bootstrap - Removing padding or margin when screen size is smaller

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

**EDITED:** 
Maybe I should ask which selector sets up the side padding when the screen is reduced to below 480px width? I have been browsing bootstrap-responsiveness.css for a while to locate this but nothing seems to affect this.

**Original**
I basically want to remove any default padding or margin set for responsiveness on smaller device screens.

I have a `background color` overridden on `container-fluid` selector and for larger screen  they render perfectly 100% across the width but they the screen is reduced to smaller sizes,
by default, Bootstrap seems to add a margin or padding on`container-fluid` or `container`.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      test
    </div>
</div>
```

If I use custom css to overwriting Bootstrap's default style, what media query or selector should I overwrite to for removing this padding on smaller screens?

Comment: Actually the padding is added to the body.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

The @media query specifically for 'phones' is..

```
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```

But, you may want to remove the padding/margin for any smaller screen sizes. By default, Bootstrap adjusts margins/padding to the body, container and navbars at 978px.

Here are some queries that have worked (in most cases) for me:

```
@media (max-width: 978px) {
    .container {
      padding:0;
      margin:0;
    }

    body {
      padding:0;
    }

    .navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-fixed-bottom, .navbar-static-top {
      margin-left: 0;
      margin-right: 0;
      margin-bottom:0;
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://bootply.com/60781)

---

**Update for Bootstrap 4**

Use the new responsive [spacing utils](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) which let you set padding/margins for different screen widths (breakpoints):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43208888/171456

Comment: Yes! finally located what sets this behaviour. You spotted my problem on point. Thanks very much.

Comment: Maybe I had an similar issue, but was related to the padding between body and the actual .container class. The container was really small for Iphone 5 screen, spacing utils didn't help me at all, instead, I edit body style directly, changing the padding from 50px to 15px, now we have much more space on screen.

Answer (score 24):

The problem here is much more complex than removing the container padding since the grid structure relies on this padding when applying negative margins for the enclosed rows.

Removing the container padding in this case will cause an x-axis overflow caused by all the rows inside of this container class, this is one of the most stupid things about the Bootstrap Grid.

Logically it should be approached by

1. Never using the `.container` class for anything other than rows
2. Make a clone of the `.container` class that has no padding for use with non-grid html
3. For removing the `.container` padding on mobile you can manually remove it with media queries then `overflow-x: hidden;` which is not very reliable but works in most cases.

If you are using `LESS` the end result will look like this

```
@media (max-width: @screen-md-max) {
    .container{
        padding: 0;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
}
```

Change the media query to whatever size you want to target.

Final thoughts, I would highly recommend using the [`Foundation Framework`](http://foundation.zurb.com) Grid as its way more advanced

Comment: This still works for Bootstrap 4, if for some reason you don't want to use `px-sm-0` on columns.

Comment: This is the real answer. I'm here just because of the overflow issue.

Answer (score 24):

The easy solution is to write something like that,

**px-lg-1**

**mb-lg-5**

By adding lg, the class will be applied only on large screens

Answer (score 8):

This thread was helpful in finding the solution in my particular case (bootstrap 3)

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .container-fluid, .row {
    padding:0px;
  }
  .navbar-header {
    margin:0px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

To solve problems like this I'm using CSS - fastest & simplest way I think... Just modify it by your needs...

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #your_id {width:000px;height:000px;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    #your_id {width:000px;height:000px;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
    #your_id {width:000px;height:000px;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 959px) {
    #your_id {width:000px;height:000px;}
}
```

Comment: sorry..it doesn't overwrite the padding for this matter simply by adding a selector...

Comment: @tassoevan I am afraid I already knew if 000px was the same as 0 and
changing 000px to 0 won't solve the problem plus, I don't know if it's a good idea to set a width to a pixel value even to 0..It's something to do with margin or padding I guess.

Comment: "000" was just example. You should write #your_id {margin:5px;padding:0px;} instead of #your_id {width:000px;height:000px;}

Comment: Try to always write proper code! Beginners might find it confusing! :)

Answer (score 6):

for Bootstrp 5 use .g-0 .g-md-1 this will set gutters zero for screen size smaller than 576px

```
<div class="container g-0 g-md-1"> ... </div>
```

Comment: it helped me! If we were close, I'd give you a hug, bro.

Answer (score 3):

The way I get an element to go 100% width of the device is use negative left and right margins on it. The body has a padding of 24px, so that's what you can use negative margins for:

```
element{
    margin-left:  -24px;
    margin-right: -24px;
    padding-left:  24px;
    padding-right:  24px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Bootstrap 4, the 15px margin the initial container has, cascades down to all rows and columns. So, something like this works for me...

```
@media (max-width: 576px) {
    .container-fluid {
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }

    .row {
        margin-left: -5px;
        margin-right: -5px;
    }
    .col, .col-1, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-auto, .col-lg, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-auto, .col-md, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-auto, .col-sm, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-auto, .col-xl, .col-xl-1, .col-xl-10, .col-xl-11, .col-xl-12, .col-xl-2, .col-xl-3, .col-xl-4, .col-xl-5, .col-xl-6, .col-xl-7, .col-xl-8, .col-xl-9, .col-xl-auto {
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }
    .row.no-gutters {
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: underrated answer, this helped me get rid of a horizontal scrollbar on mobile

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem occur on sites that used similar formatting and code and I have racked my brain over what was the missing detail that made some of my sites work, and some not.

For Bootstrap 3: The answer for me was not in rewriting css for .container-fluid, .row or resetting margins, the consistent pattern that I realized was the **length of longer words were throwing off the design and creating margins**.

The solution steps:

1. Test your page by temporarily deleting sections that contain containers and test your site on small browsers.  This will identify your problem container.
2. You may have a div formatting problem.  If you do, fix it.  If all is well then:
3. Identify if you have used long words that are not wrapping.  If you cannot change the word (like for tag lines or slogans, etc.)

Solution 1:  Format the font to smaller size in your media query for smaller screen (I usually find @media (max-width: 767px) to be sufficient).

OR:

Solution 2:

```
@media (max-width: 767px){

h1, h2, h3 {word-wrap: break-word;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The CSS by Paulius Marčiukaitis worked nicely for my Genesis theme, here's what how I further modified it for my requirement:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.entry {
background-color: #fff;
margin-bottom: 0;
padding: 10px 8px;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
.container-fluid {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
}
```

Comment: From Review Que: Could you elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Heres what I do for Bootstrap 3/4

Use container-fluid instead of container.

Add this to my CSS

```
@media (min-width: 1400px) {
    .container-fluid{
        max-width: 1400px;
    }   
}
```

This removes margins below 1400px width screen

Answer (score 0):

Another css that can make the margin problem is that you have `direction:someValue` in your css, so just remove it by setting it to initial.

For example:

```
body {
     direction:rtl;
 }
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
     direction:initial;
    }
}
```