# Bootstrap - Removing padding or margin for figures when screen size is smaller

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to have an image that covers the whole screen (without margin or padding) on small devices. Techniques propsed [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16410659/bootstrap-removing-padding-or-margin-when-screen-size-is-smaller) unfortunately did not work for me.
Here is the code I currently have. (tested on `https://jsfiddle.net/`).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid bg-primary">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9">
  <div class="image-wraper">
    <figure class="figure">
            <img
                src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/8-col/img%20(73).jpg"
                class="figure-img img-fluid rounded shadow-3 mb-1"
                alt="Taking up Water with a Spoon"
                style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: cover;"
            />
            <figcaption class=" figure-caption">A caption for the above image.</figcaption>
        </figure>
  </div>
    
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    ... 
  </div>
  </div>
        
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

There is still a margin on the left and right. How can I remove it on screen less than or equal to `sm` ?

Answer (score 1):

The picture fills the screen completely, but since the aspect ratio does not fully match the aspect ratio of the screen, I got the following result. I also applied my own style by canceling the Bootstrap link. Can you test it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0px !important;
        }

        img {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .img-fluid {
            max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }

        .figure-style {
            margin: 0px !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <figure class="figure-style">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/8-col/img%20(73).jpg"/>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Application test image is available below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Sercan. This effectively covers the whole screen. But I forgot to say that it should be inside a `<div class="col-md-9">`.

Comment: Just to double check @Kyv .... If you have it inside a `col-9` then by default it is never going to stretch the entire screen width but only three quarters of it... Eg col-9 out of of 12 possible columns and 12 will be full width full width as @SercanSebetçi suggested in his code above

Answer (score 0):

If you have an image with an aspect ratio suitable for browser screen in **Bootstrap 5**, you can apply the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/new/slides/041.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Wild Landscape" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using media query, By default Bootstrap adjusts margins/padding to the body, container and navbars at 480px.

```
@media(max - width: 480 px) {
   ...
}
```