# Is there a way to remove padding-x from bootstrap column on mobile without custom css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Because Bootstrap gives the possibility of managing styles from classes, I was wondering if I could remove the column padding on mobile only with bootstrap classes.

You can remove padding on larger screens by using for example `px-lg-0` but it seems that you can't get the same result with smaller screen.

I tryed `px-0 px-lg-1`, `px-0 px-lg-2` or `px-0 px-lg-3` but none of them have the same padding as the original column padding.

You can see the issue in the snippet below by running it on full screen with a width >= 992px.

```css
.container{
  border:3px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 bg-light text-dark">A</div>
      <div class="col-12 bg-dark text-light px-0 px-lg-2">B</div>
      <div class="col-12 bg-light text-dark px-0 px-lg-3">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: B & C has 0 padding on screen. it's working properly I can't see where it doesn't.

Comment: @UNRIVALLEDKING Try running the snippet in full page, screen width >= 992px

Comment: you want padding x 0 in large screen?? then replace `px-lg-2` and `px-lg-3`  with `px-lg-0`

Comment: @UNRIVALLEDKING Thanks for trying to help but you did not understand the question. I'm asking if there is a way to remove the padding on small screen but keep the original padding on large screen without custom css.

Comment: I dont think there is a good reason to not use custom CSS, but maybe look arround column size like `col-xs` or `col-sm` ...
Otherwise, maybe this post could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16410659/bootstrap-removing-padding-or-margin-when-screen-size-is-smaller

Comment: @EmeraldCottet Because if I can do it without custom css, I shouldn't add css that would do the same thing. The library provides tools to manage spaces so I'm surprised that you can do something in one way but not the other.

Comment: @Cédric I get your query now, sorry i misunderstood before, the difference of that padding is cause of `$spacer` as you might know that margin and padding in bootstrap works like this `.px-2 {
  padding-left: ($spacer * .5) !important;
  padding-right: ($spacer * .5) !important;
}` by default spacer value is 1rem you can change it . check bootstrap documentation for more info [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/theming/#variable-defaults) you have to find the default padding of that col and set spacer variable according to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap provides [gutters](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/gutters) class that enable you to change the value of the variable used for the padding.

Instead of `px-0 px-lg-3`, I can use `gx-0 gx-lg-4`.

```css
.container{
  border:3px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 bg-light text-dark">A</div>
    <div class="col-12 bg-dark text-light gx-0 gx-lg-4">B</div>
    <div class="col-12 bg-light text-dark gx-0 gx-lg-4">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, I am understanding you correctly. You could test setting "--bs-gutter-x" to "0" for .container in a custom css file if you don't want to go the SASS route, as in the following (see the snippet in action at https://codepen.io/sam-miller-the-flexboxer/pen/mdxbQGr)?

```css
.container{
  border:3px solid orange;
  /* redefined bootstrap variable */
  --bs-gutter-x: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 bg-light text-dark">A</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 bg-dark text-light">B</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 bg-light text-dark">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Also, unless you need to have columns with and without container spacing, I would apply the padding settings to the container div itself rather than the individual columns:

For example,

```
<div class="container px-0 px-lg-3">
```

Comment: I made a snippet with 1 column per line to make it more clear but I need multiples columns per line in desktop, and I need to remove the column padding. In my situation `px-lg-3` wont work as I mentioned in the question.